# Description of the first IC

Tags: integrated-circuit

I wonder what is the description of the first IC made by Kilby. The famous picture is shown in many websites, but I want to know what it is?!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it is a phase-shift oscillator that worked at about 1.3 MHz. Kilby first demonstrated a flip-flop built entirely with semiconductor elements, but it was not a monolithic part—it was assembled from individual elements.

The first IC was a phase-shift oscillator. From Kilby's [own account](http://corphist.computerhistory.org/corphist/documents/doc-496d289787271.pdf):

[image: scanned paragraph]

Comment: I believe you mean Kilby, not Kirby.

Comment: Indeed... This is [Jack Kilby](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cc/Jack_Kilby.jpg) and this is [Nintendo's Kirby](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/22/Kirby_Wii.png).

Comment: @haneefmubarak ...though a noteworthy [Jack Kirby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Kirby) does also exist.

Answer (score 8):

The history of Kilby's ICs can be found [here](http://www.ti.com/corp/docs/company/history/timeline/semicon/1950/docs/58ic_kilby.htm).

The IC is a phase-shift oscillator. Excerpts (emphasis mine):

> He sketched in his notebook the complete circuit of a phase-shift
>   oscillator on a bar of germanium.
>
> Within two weeks, the first three oscillators were completed and ready
>   to test. What TI managers saw on that historic day of September 12,
>   1958, was a **tiny bar of germanium, measuring 7/16-x1/16-inches, with
>   protruding wires, glued to a glass slide**. It was a rough device by
>   anyone's standards. But when Kilby applied the voltage, an unending
>   sine wave undulated across the oscilloscope screen.

[Here](http://www.ti.com/corp/docs/kilbyctr/jackbuilt.shtml) is another, more general account of that story.

Comment: That was a quick edit. ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yep! Sorry, I highlighted and read the wrong part, and I realized it too late! :-)